# Issue with selection in Screenshot manager

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have built custom state saving functionality into our web app, based largely on the "Screenshot Manager" extension that Philippe created. We are having an issue with selection, wherein some components that where hidden when the state was saved are being shown when the state is loaded. I have replicated it on viewer.autodesk.io with the vanilla states manager code.

To be precise, components already visible in the viewer that are hidden by CTRL-clicking them on the model browser initially disappear in the viewer. However, when you save this state and then recall the state at a later time, the components hidden in this way re-appear.

Can you please investigate - is this a bug in the states manager code (we had a look but can't find it - the hidden components are being recorded in the state) or in the viewer itself?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: By "Screenshot Manager" I assume you actually mean "State Manager", otherwise the question would be quite confusing ... so far I'm not reproducing the issue as you describe it. Can you take a look at my latest sample at: https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/viewer?id=57efaead77c8eb0a560ef465. I created 2 states "direct hide" and "browser hide" which seem to work fine to me. Also a saved state is just a json object, so you can easily take a look what your saved state looks like and see if the selected hidden dbIds have been correctly saved in the state.

Comment: You can also use the non-minified version of the viewer3D.js and place break points in "restoreState" function to check what is going on there.

Comment: Hi Philippe. Sorry - I am referring to the "States Manager" and I can replicate on your latest code by doing the following: In the model browser select sub-assembly D-400687:1. Then CTRL-Click on the part D400550:1 to hide it. Save the state. Then load a previous state and return to the new state. You will find that part D400550:1 will be visible in the state. You can also replicate by selecting the same part in the viewer and hiding it via right click. It still comes back. As far as we can tell the dbIds aren't being stored in the JSON object.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue as you describe it, take a look a this short recording and let me know what I am missing: https://www.screencast.com/t/Xpn1pZ5g

Comment: First select the Sub Assembly D-400687:1 so the rest of the seat is hidden. Then try hiding the same part. See this video and check out the states I have saved in the viewer. https://www.screencast.com/t/6Evm2htB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check what happen when you select components, those 2 states are incompatible: the child gets hidden but the parent gets isolated, hence it is displaying all its children and hide the rest of the components in the model.

In order to get the behavior you "would" expect, you would need to hide all components without isolating the parent sub-assemlbly, then create your first state, then hide the child, create your second state. You may achieve that by writing your handler when clicking a browser node. For that you would need to implement your own ModelStructurePanel.

I've got a basic example which can help you getting started:

[ModelStructurePanel](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/tree/master/src/Viewing.Extension.CustomModelStructure)

I will take a look at the click handler and add an example there. For the time being, you can check in the source of the viewer3D.js which methods you need to overwrite.

Hope that helps